# Find if there are two specfic characters in a string

Tags: java, string, char, substring

I'm doing some java exercises and I can't figure why the answer isn't this one.

```
 for (int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++)  {
    if ((str.charAt(i)=='b') && (str.charAt(i+2)=='b')) {
    return true; }
    else return false; 
    }
 return false;
```

The question asks to return true if a given string(str) has "bob" in it, except the middle character does not need to be "o". The above code returns true for strings three characters 
in length which meet the condition, like "bob" or "bbb", but false for strings longer than that i.e "bobdfgkabcb". I've literally spent all day trying to solve this and another similar problem so I'd be gratefull to be told why its wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: @TheLostMind or the 1st!

Comment: And you shouldn't return false in the else block. This `else` will abort your loop in the first iteration. You should remove it.

Comment: Is it forbidden to use regex for this exercise ?

Comment: Aha thank you! I knew it would be something silly and blindingly obvious to someone who knows. Also I don't think regex is forbidden, but if I'm messing this up, I should practice this level of thing a bit longer:)  Thanks @TheLostMind et al.

Comment: If the 1st `str.charAt(i+2)=='b'` is true, you would hope the 2nd `str.charAt(i+2)=='b'` is also true.

Comment: Typo! Edited! Sarcasm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
for (int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++)  {
    if ((str.charAt(i)=='b') && (str.charAt(i+2)=='b')) {// check 1st and 3rd character, 2nd and 4th character etc
    return true; }
    }
 return false;
```

Or you could try regex like this : `str.matches(".*b[a-zA-Z]b.*")`

Comment: Does it need  to be a loop if it's just the 1st and 3rd char? Surely if it *has* to be 3 chars long it can be a simple if. Unless I misunderstood. So start with a `if(str.length() > 3) return false;`

Comment: @Yann4 - I think The Op also wants to check in the String `dadsabobsada`. We could use a simple regex, but I don't think the OP would understand that.

Comment: In the question it says " but false for strings longer than that i.e "bobdfgkabcb"."

Answer (score 0):

you can use to it:

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length()-2 ; i++){
  if( str.substring(i , i+1).equals("b") && str.substring(i+2 , i+3).equals("b"))
  return true;}

  return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a string error so this was my solution:

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) {
boolean returner = false;
if(str.contains("bob")){
  return true;
}
for(int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++){
  if(str.charAt(i) == 'b'){
      if(str.charAt(i + 2) == 'b')
       returner = true;
 
  }
}
if(returner == true){
  return returner;
}
return false;
}
```

If you get the error, minus the length by the location of the second variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation which uses indexOf() method of String instead.

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) {
      int c=str.indexOf('b');
      int l=str.length();
      for(;c<l-2 && c!=-1;c=str.indexOf('b',c))
      {
      if(str.charAt(c+2)=='b') 
      return true;
      c++;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean bobThere(String str) {
    if(str.length()<3)
        return false;
    else {
        for(int i=0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
            if(str.charAt(i)=='b'&&str.charAt(i+2)=='b') return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```